# Inserting A 2D array into another 2D array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, insert

I want to insert a numpy array A of size 508x12 into another numpy array B of size 508x13 resulting in an array of size 508x25. But here is the thing, i don't just want to concatanete them, but insted insert the array at one specific column location c.
[image]

How would I do that?, I have tried:

```
C = np.insert(B, c, A, axis=1)
```

Comment: Hello! I am not too sure if this is possible with insert(), maybe someone will bring up a better answer.

But in the meantime, I'd suggest that you can relatively safely use something like `C = np.concatenate([B[:, 0:c], A, B[:, c:]], axis=1)`, in case this helps.
I hope I got the dimensions right.

Answer (score 1):

Just split up the concatenation like @brezniczky suggested. Alternatively, use hstack:

```
import numpy as np


a = np.ones((508,12))
b = np.zeros((508,13))

col = 3

final = np.hstack((b[:,0:col],a,b[:,col:])) 

print(final[0])
```

[0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0.]

In this scenario hstack and concatenation with axis=1 are the same, I just prefer hstack for better readability